# A few were, or a few was?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

If I write:

> Only a few of his friends were are at this side

is this correct? Or should **'were'** be **'was'** as a few is singular?

Comment: Is "were are" a typo?

Comment: The meaning of the complex determiner "a few" is such that the embedded NP can only be plural, so "were" must be correct.

Answer (score 2):

I must first correct another part of your sentence: you wrote **were are at this side** – I think you meant either

> Only a few of his friends **were** at *his* side.

or

> Only a few of his friends **are** at *his* side.

In this structure of this sentence, **few** is an [indefinite pronoun](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000027.htm) referring to *friends*, and since *friends* is plural, you use **were** and not **was**.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out and apologies for the sloppy writing...

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help you out.